# iOS 11, Cordova app sidebar disappears on scroll

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova, ios11

we published several apps based on Cordova for iOS. The graphical interface framework we used was AdminLTE, derived from Bootstrap. 
In all the apps, we have a sidebar, whose position is fixed in CSS. Beside it, we have a scrollable content (a series of LI inside an UL list). Everything was fine until iOS 10, but now we have a strange behaviour. Scrolling the content, the sidebar simply disappears.
I have read many suggestions (especially this [Overflow scrolling not working on position fixed element iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914983/overflow-scrolling-not-working-on-position-fixed-element-ios)). 
None of the solutions really work. But the strangest thing is that this behaviour only started in betas of iOS11 (while the proposed solutions are from iOS 5 and later).

When I say it does not work, I mean that this fix:

```
.main-sidebar * {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
```

applies correctly to the first inner element of .main-sidebar, while the other sub-elements still disappear.

So, anybody has faced this particular situation?

Thanks
Fabio

Comment: Have had this issue, but not sure how to solve it. If you find out, find answer the question! :)

Comment: similar to the issue, the header and footer also disappears on scroll then appears again when scrolling stops , no solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving an actual value to the z axis. ie: `transform: translate3d(0,0,1px)`.

I've found that I have better luck engaging hardware acceleration with that, rather than an empty zero value.

But I doubt it'll fix the problem entirely. I'm having all sorts of disappearing content issues with iOS 11 and can't fix them. Strangely, I can't reproduce them in the normal mobile Safari browser. They only show in the headless web view.